# Find the equation of a circle given a point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to solve the same excercise that was posted an hour ago by another user, I read the answer and it makes perfect sense, this was the question and the answer:
Find the ordinary differential equation for the family of circumferences with radius equal to $1$ and whose center is in the circumference
$x^2+y^2=25$

Suppose you had an ODE which, when solved, gave you a circle in the family of circles with radius $1$ with center distance $5$ from the origin. In addition, assume that it is 1st order.

Note that given any point distance between $4$ and $6$ from the origin, there are $2$ circles in your family that go through it; this means that, given a fixed $x$ and $y$ in your ODE, there must be $2$ solutions for $y'$. This suggests a quadratic ODE in $y'$.

Thus, to figure out the answer, pick an arbitrary point $(x_0,y_0)$ in the plane; find the equations of the circles in your family that intersect $(x_0,y_0)$; find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ for each of those circles, giving two values $r_0(x_0,y_0)$ and $r_1(x_0,y_0)$ (or 1 value $r_0=r_1$ if you have a degeneracy); and construct the quadratic $(y'−r_0)(y'−r_1)=0$ which will be your desired ODE.

My question is, how do I find the equations od the circles, given the values of, for example $(0,4)$?

I think I'm doing it the wrong way on my own, thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps to readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would go about finding an ODE. Given $(x,y)$, we seek a direction $(dx,dy)$ such that if we rotate the vector $(dx,dy)$ by 90 degrees and go $1$ unit of distance in that direction, we'll arrive at the circle of radius $5$. Now, there are two ways to rotate a vector by 90 degrees: clockwise $(dy,-dx)$ and counterclockwise $(-dy,dx)$. The first gives the equation
$$\left|(x,y)+\frac{(dy,-dx)}{\sqrt{dy^2+dx^2}} \right|=5$$
or, written in a more conventional form,
$$\left|(x,y)+\frac{(y',-1)}{\sqrt{(y')^2+1}} \right|=5$$
Computing the distance yields
$$\left(x+\frac{y'}{\sqrt{(y')^2+1}} \right)^2+ 
\left(y-\frac{1}{\sqrt{(y')^2+1}} \right)^2-25=0 \tag1 $$
The other choice of direction 
yields
$$\left(x-\frac{y'}{\sqrt{(y')^2+1}} \right)^2+ 
\left(y+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(y')^2+1}} \right)^2-25=0\tag2 $$
In principle, one can multiply (1) and (2) to form one equation.

---

I would not know what to do with such ODEs.